# Can't access $http data in angular in bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have already used the search function, but I didn't find a solution that solves my problem.
I'm having the UI Bootstrap directives in Angular. Before opening the modal, I want to make a $hhtp get call to get the data for the modal. Almost everything works perfectly, except the data is not present in the first opening the modal. When I click again the data is present.

Here's my code:

```js
myapp.controller( 'jobsController', [ '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$modal', function( $rootScope, $scope, $http, $modal ) {

    $scope.post = [];

    $scope.getJobs = function(id) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.api,
            params: {
                'type' : 'jobs',
                'filter[p]' : id,
                'filter[post_status]' : 'publish'
            }
        }).
        success( function( data ) {
            $scope.post = data[0];
        });

    };

    $scope.open = function(id) {

        $scope.getJobs(id);

        $scope.opts = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            backdropClick: true,
            scope: (function () {
                var scope = $rootScope.$new();
                scope.post = $scope.post;
                return scope;
            })(),
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        };
      
        $modal.open($scope.opts);
    };

}]);

myapp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

I have tried several tutorials and code snippets from this site and others, but I did not find the solution. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $http.get is an async call. The call needs to "come back" before accessing the data.

```
$scope.getJobs = function(id) {

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $scope.api,
        params: {
            'type' : 'jobs',
            'filter[p]' : id,
            'filter[post_status]' : 'publish'
        }
    });

};

$scope.open = function(id) {

    $scope.getJobs(id).
    then( function( data ) {
        $scope.post = data[0];

        $scope.opts = {
          backdrop: true,
          keyboard: true,
          backdropClick: true,
          scope: (function () {
            var scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.post = $scope.post;
            return scope;
          })(),
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        };

        $modal.open($scope.opts);

    });
};
```

So in order to make it work, the easiest way is to deal with the resolve of the promise inside your `open` function.

---

PS : your code works, but is not really angular-styled, nor efficient.

- You don't need to put all of your objects inside $scope. You can also create local variables if you only need them inside your controller. 
  eg :

  $scope.opts = {};

can be replace by :

```
var opts = {};
```

This will prevent angular from checking the value of your variables everytime it `$digest()`

- delegate your server calls to a service. You will be able to share your calls between controllers.
- if possible use the `controller as` syntax.

Do not hesitate to read this styleguide : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Thx a lot... i'm pretty new to angular so i'm thankful for every hint ;).
Btw your solution is working perfect!